# Antd radio circle falls outside

Tags: javascript, css, radio-button, antd

I using radio button in React js App.
And lately i noticed that in radio button cicrle falls outside the button.
I thought maybe there are something wrong with margins, paddings.
But when i removed all margins, styles, classNames and so on.
Issue still didn't dissapear.
When i tried to use the same ANTD component in another page, it was the same problem.
I didn't use any specific styles in index.css
Did anyone had this issue before with `ANTD Radio`
Sorry i didn't provide any code.
But i don't even have anything to provide.
I literelly deleted everything that was possible

[image]

Comment: Which antd version are you using? If possible please provide codesandbox link for your issue. Thank you :)

Comment: @Ved Hi Ved it's ^4.13.0

Comment: Did you inspect the element in the browser and checked the CSS styles for the radio button?

Comment: Yes, i complitely removed all possible styles from web app.
And inscpected styles 'ant-radio ant-radio-checked' as well, but didn't find even a single padding or margin there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a css file for your component and add the following css. Your issue is most probably due to the `position` property which is overriden by some other css

`position` should be `position: absolute;`

default antd `.ant-radio-inner::after` should be as follows

```css
.ant-radio-inner::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    display: block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    margin-top: -8px;
    margin-left: -8px;
    background-color: #1890ff;
    border-top: 0;
    border-left: 0;
    border-radius: 16px;
    transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.78, 0.14, 0.15, 0.86);
    content: ' ';
}
```

When `position` property is removed from above class you get this issue, check the following screenshot

After removing `position: absolute;` property

[image: Screenshot]

After adding `position: absolute;` property:

[image: Screenshot]

I hope this helps you.., Thank you :)